# PL/SQL compilation error with declaring variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a basic PL/SQL query where I am using a certain SKU as a parameter so that I can reference it without typing in the sku each time.

When compiling my code I get the error:

> Error report:
>   ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
>   PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

Here is my code:

```
declare
myitem number (20);
begin 
myitem := 1000956;

select f.order_no
from fdt_maptool f
where f.item = myitem;

end; 
/
```

I thought that maybe it had to do with me using VARCHAR(20) instead of NUMBER, So I tried that as well.

```
declare
myitem number;
begin 
myitem := 1000956;

select f.order_no
from fdt_maptool f
where f.item = myitem;

end; 
/
```

And then received this error:

> Error report:
>   ORA-06550: line 6, column 1:
>   PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
>   06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>   *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
>   *Action:

I am fairly new to PL/SQL so if please go easy on me!

Comment: You need to select the results of the query into a variable. E.g. `select f.order_no into v_order_no from ...`, assuming that f.item is a unique column.

Comment: I actually do not have administrative clearance on this Database, It will not let me create/delete/insert/ etc... on any of the databases. Is this the only way to set a reference variable?

Comment: If you can select from the table, then you can create an anonymous PL/SQL block that contains a variable that you can select into. Although if all you want to do is to run a repeatable query with different parameters, then perhaps you need just the sql statement, and a where clause of `...where f.item = :p_item` or maybe `...where f.item = &item`.

Comment: Is there a way to just use &myitem after is has been declared in the declaration statement at the beginning?

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to achieve with this procedure that you couldn't do with straight sql statements?

Comment: I wanted to have a reference parameter that I could implement within this program so that I could learn to use them in bigger programs that my company has. I’ve read of putting the & in front of a variable but other than that I am lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within PLSQL you need to select into

```
declare
   myitem number(20);
   myorder number(20);
begin 
   myitem := 1000956;

   select f.order_no
   into myorder
   from fdt_maptool f
   where f.item = myitem;

end; 
/
```

Now there's  two standard things that might go wrong. You may not find a record or you may find more than one record. You need exception handlers to handle these cases.

```
declare
   myitem number(20);
   myorder number(20);
begin 
   myitem := 1000956;

   select f.order_no
   into myorder
   from fdt_maptool f
   where f.item = myitem;

exception
   when no_data_found then
    dbms_output.put_line('No record with this ID');

   -- Only needed when not selecting a unique column.
   when too_many_rows then
    dbms_output.put_line('More than one record with this ID');

end; 
/
```

Note that the too_many_rows exception is usually already covered by the fact that you are selecting an ID column that has a unique constraint defined on it.

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly! Now, I have one more question. Is it possible to be able to see multiple tables from this data instead fo just bringing back one order_no? I tried using the "select * " and it did not work.